Rails7でwebpackerからvite_railsに移行したが@rails/ujsが読み込めずにdestroyリクエストがgetリクエストになってしまう
前提
私はRails6で構成されていたアプリをRails7にバージョンアップした。
同時にwebpackerからviteに移行しました。
開発環境では問題なく動いていますが、本番環境ではrails/ujsがうまく動作していません。
現状
ブラウザのconsoleタグで以下のエラーが表示されている。
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'Rails')
各種関連ファイルは以下の通りです。
vite.config.mts
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import Rails from "vite-plugin-rails";
import inject from "@rollup/plugin-inject";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    inject({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
    }),
    react(),
    Rails({
      fullReload: {
        additionalPaths: ["config/routes.rb", "app/views/**/*"],
        delay: 200,
      },
    }),
  ],
});

app/frontend/entrypoints/application.js
import jquery from "jquery";
window.jQuery = jquery;
window.$ = jquery;

import * as Rails from "@rails/ujs";
Rails.start();

import "bootstrap";
import "popper.js";
import "@nathanvda/cocoon";

import "./main.js";
import "./select2.full.min.js";
import flatpickr from 'flatpickr';
import { Japanese } from "flatpickr/dist/l10n/ja.js"

import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage";
... 以下省略

試したこと
グローバルスコープで定義してみたり
import * as Rails from "@rails/ujs";
window.Rails = Rails;
Rails.start();

vite.configの定義の仕方を変えてみたりしたがうまくいきませんでした。
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    inject({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      Rails: ['@rails/ujs', 'default'],
    }),

